# How to fill histogram with color gradient?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, color-palette

I have a simple problem. How to plot histogram with `ggplot2` with fixed `binwidth` and filled with rainbow colors (or any other palette)?

Lets say I have a data like that:

```
myData <- abs(rnorm(1000))
```

I want to plot histogram, using e.g. `binwidth=.1`. That however will cause different number of bins, depending on data:

```
ggplot() + geom_histogram(aes(x = myData), binwidth=.1)
```

[image]

If I knew number of bins (e.g. `n=15`) I'd use something like:

```
ggplot() + geom_histogram(aes(x = myData), binwidth=.1, fill=rainbow(n))
```

But with changing number of bins I'm kind of stuck on this simple problem.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you want each bin of the histogram to be coloured differently according to a rainbow gradient?

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I want

Comment: @user20650 I saw this answer, but over there number of bins is fixed so its not solving my problem.

Comment: @yup agreed   ...

Comment: Why not just force the number of bins through the `bins` argument?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik: Because I need to have fixed bin width not fixed number of bins. If I could do that I wouldn't ask :)

Comment: This seems to work... `n <- round(((max(myData)-min(myData))/.1)+1)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you really want the number of bins flexible, here is my little workaround:

```
library(ggplot2)

gg_b <- ggplot_build(
  ggplot() + geom_histogram(aes(x = myData), binwidth=.1)
)

nu_bins <- dim(gg_b$data[[1]])[1]

ggplot() + geom_histogram(aes(x = myData), binwidth=.1, fill = rainbow(nu_bins))
```

[image]

Comment: Yep, that is exactly what I need. I was just thinking (and hoping) that there is some more straightforward method to do that :) Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In case the binwidth is fixed, here is an alternative solution which is using the internal function `ggplot2:::bin_breaks_width()` to get the number of bins *before* creating the graph. It's still a workaround but avoids to call `geom_histogram()` twice as in  [the other solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40284509/3817004):

```
# create sample data
set.seed(1L)
myData <- abs(rnorm(1000))
binwidth <- 0.1

# create plot    
library(ggplot2)   # CRAN version 2.2.1 used
n_bins <- length(ggplot2:::bin_breaks_width(range(myData), width = binwidth)$breaks) - 1L
ggplot() + geom_histogram(aes(x = myData), binwidth = binwidth, fill = rainbow(n_bins))
```

[image]

---

As a third alternative, the aggregation can be done outside of `ggplot2`. Then, `geom_col()` cam be used instead of `geom_histogram()`:

```
# start binning on multiple of binwidth
start_bin <- binwidth * floor(min(myData) / binwidth)
# compute breaks and bin the data
breaks <- seq(start_bin, max(myData) + binwidth, by = binwidth)
myData2 <- cut(sort(myData), breaks = breaks, by = binwidth)

ggplot() + geom_col(aes(x = head(breaks, -1L), 
                        y = as.integer(table(myData2)), 
                        fill = levels(myData2))) + 
  ylab("count") + xlab("myData")
```

[image]

Note that `breaks` is plotted on the x-axis instead of  `levels(myData2)` to keep the x-axis continuous. Otherwise each factor label would be plotted which would clutter the x-axis. Also note that the built-in `ggplot2` color palette is used instead of `rainbow()`.