# Weird behavior of ggplot combined with fill and scale_y_log10()

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I'm trying to produce a histogram with `ggplot'`s `geom_histogram` which colors the bars according to a gradient, and log10's them.

Here's the code:

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(id=paste("ID",1:1000,sep="."),val=rnorm(1000),stringsAsFactors=F)

bins <- 10
cols <- c("darkblue","darkred")
colGradient <- colorRampPalette(cols)
cut.cols <- colGradient(bins)
df$cut <- cut(df$val,bins)
df$cut <- factor(df$cut,level=unique(df$cut))
```

Then,

```
ggplot(data=df,aes_string(x="val",y="..count..+1",fill="cut"))+
  geom_histogram(show.legend=FALSE)+
  scale_color_manual(values=cut.cols,labels=levels(df$cut))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=cut.cols,labels=levels(df$cut))+
  scale_y_log10()
```

gives:[image]

whereas dropping the `fill` from the `aesthetics`:

```
ggplot(data=df,aes_string(x="val",y="..count..+1"))+
  geom_histogram(show.legend=FALSE)+
  scale_color_manual(values=cut.cols,labels=levels(cuts))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=cut.cols,labels=levels(cuts))+
  scale_y_log10()
```

gives:[image]

Any idea why do the histogram bars differ between the two plots and to make the first one similar to the second one?

Comment: By default, `geom_histogram` uses `position_stack`. You can change that to `position_identity`, but then you might want to make the bars transparent. I recommend using faceting instead.

Answer (score 3):

The OP is *trying to produce a histogram with ggplot's geom_histogram which colors the bars according to a gradient...*

The OP has already done the binning (with 10 bins) but is then  calling `geom_histogram()` which does a binning on its own using 30 bins by default (see `?geomhistogram`).

When `geom_bar()` is used instead together with `cut`instead of `val`

```
ggplot(data = df, aes_string(x = "cut", y = "..count..+1", fill = "cut")) +
  geom_bar(show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_color_manual(values = cut.cols, labels = levels(df$cut)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = cut.cols, labels = levels(df$cut)) +
  scale_y_log10()
```

the chart becomes:

[image]

Using `geom_histogram()` with filled bars is less straightforward as can be seen in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40284509/3817004) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44591045/3817004) to the question [How to fill histogram with color gradient?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40284227/3817004)