# Fill histogram bins with a custom gradient

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, gradient

I want to create a histogram in R and ggplot2, in which the bins are filled based on their continuous x-value. Most tutorials only feature coloring by discrete values or density/count.

Following [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40284227/how-to-fill-histogram-with-color-gradient) was able to color the bins with a rainbow scale:

```
df <- data.frame(x = runif(100))

ggplot(df) +
  geom_histogram(aes(x), fill = rainbow(30))
```

[Rainbow histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CQ4I.png)

I want to use a color gradient, where the bins are from blue (lowest) to yellow (highest). The `scale_fill_gradient()` function seems to achive that, yet when i insert it in place of `rainbow()` for the `fill` argument i receive an error:

```
> ggplot(df) +
+ geom_histogram(aes(x), fill = scale_fill_gradient(low='blue', high='yellow'))

Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (30): fill
```

I tried several ways to supply the length of 30 for the scale, yet i get the same error every time. So my question is:

1. Is `scale_color_gradient` the right function for the `fill` argument or do i have to use another one?
2. If it is the right function, how can i correctly supply the length?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want different colors for each bin, you need to specify `fill = ..x..` in the aesthetics, which is a necessary quirk of `geom_histogram`. Using `scale_fill_gradient` with your preferred color gradient then yields the following output:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, fill = ..x..)) +
  geom_histogram() +
  scale_fill_gradient(low='blue', high='yellow')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you - exactly what i was looking for. I've encountered other variables like `..count..` or `..density..` before, but was unable to find how many or which there are exactly.