# Coloring a geom_histogram by "label fraction" in a R dataframe?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

Suppose I have the dataframe like below:

```
df <- data.frame(x = runif(100))
df$x2 = df$x*100
cut = quantile(df$x2, 0.75)
df$label = ifelse(df$x2>cut, 1, 0)

          x       x2 label
1 0.1431888 14.31888     0
2 0.9131599 91.31599     1
3 0.5659831 56.59831     0
4 0.8358059 83.58059     1
5 0.3125397 31.25397     0
6 0.8823542 88.23542     1
```

The task is:

Firstly, to show the histogram of `x`, which can be done using the `geom_histogram()`

Secondly, in each bin, I want to color the bin by the fraction of label equals 1 in this bin.

I am confused about how to achieve it. Because I need to know the number of 1 in this bin and the number of point in this bin, which is difficult for me how to do it (the binwidth is not fixed). Since I search in the website but only find that the `geom_histogram()` color change by the `x`, for example in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50150269/fill-histogram-bins-with-a-custom-gradient) .

The output result I want is like this:

[image: plot_example]:

The image is generated by the following code:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, fill = ..x..)) + geom_histogram()
```

But in this example, the color depends on `x` in each bin. However, I want the color to depend on the fraction of label equals 1 (the third column) in each bin.

Comment: Please show a sample of your  `ggplot2` code and possibly a sample of the current and expected plots.

Comment: I have add a expected plots and sample code in the Add

Answer (score 1):

We can use hist function to create the breaks and counts manually, so that we can do a mean of label inside each bin of the histogram:

```
library(dplyr)

H = hist(df$x,breaks=30,plot=FALSE)
plotdf <- df %>% 
mutate(bins=cut(df$x,breaks=H$breaks,bins=H$mids)) %>%
group_by(bins) %>%
summarise(label=mean(label),n=length(bins))
```

From here on, we plot x as the bin, y as number of counts and fill it with the mean number of label == 1:

```
ggplot(plotdf,aes(x=bins,y=n,fill=label)) + geom_col()+
scale_fill_gradient2(low="#f6e1e1",mid="#ff9d76",high="#eb4d55")+
scale_x_discrete(labels=H$mids)
```

[image]

Comment: I have another question, how to adjust the geom_col() width to close the blank between each bars? I tried to set the geom_col(width=0.05) in this case, but the width get much smaller. -_- thx~

Comment: @XiWang, try something like geom_col(width=0.98,col="black")?

Comment: thx~ I finally set geom_col(width=1,color="black"). It works well.